# Getting rowID from row of a jqgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid, checkbox, jqgrid-asp.net

In my `asp.net MVC 3` application am using `Jqgrid` as my grid. It contains a checkbox and i managed the event as below

```
 $("#list").find('input[type=checkbox]').live('change', function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    var _row = $(this).parent().parent();
}
});
```

i got the row using `$(this).parent().parent()` i want to `get the id of the _row` . How can i get the id? Is there any method please share

Comment: By *id* do you mean the `id` attribute of the `<tr>` tag or some information containing within some of the columns (`<td>`)?

Comment: id attribute if the <tr> tag . Or, actually i want the id of jqgrid row, I think can achieve that by getting id of <tr>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$('#list').find('input[type=checkbox]').live('change', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var row = $(this).parent().parent();
        var rowId = row.attr('id');
    }
});
```

If you are using default value of `idPrefix` option of jqGrid (which is empty string) otherwise the id will prepend with value of this option.

Answer (score 0):

On select row you can get the id of selected row. In fact when you check a checkbox you also select a row so:

```
onSelectRow: function(id){
yourId = $("#yourGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
alert("The id of checked row is: "+yourId);
}
```